# Show Region which was hidden when the page loaded APEX

Tags: oracle-apex

I need a region with a form to be hidden when the page loads and shown when the user is clicking on a button. I tried it with a dynamic action where I used "Show" an "Hide" but it is not working as planed. The region is displayed after loading the page.

Answer (score 2):

Server-side conditions on a component are evaluated when the page is rendered. If the condition yields false, the component is *not* included in the rendered page so it is impossible to make it visible - simply because it is not in the DOM.

The way to show/hide a region is to:

1. Not set a server-side condition
2. use a dynamic action to show/hide

Comment: I am using a dynamic action with show for true and hide for false. The region is still displayed when the page ia loading.

Comment: You could create an extra dynamic action to hide on page load.

Comment: It is working now. Thank you for your support!